# Highcharts render svg icon doesn't show

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I need to add a symbol in svg on graph and I using a

```
Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.download = function (x, y, w, h) {
    var path = [
        "M19 5v14H5V5h14m1.1-2H3.9c-.5 0-.9.4-.9.9v16.2c0 .4.4.9.9.9h16.2c.4 0 .9-.5.9-.9V3.9c0-.5-.5-.9-.9-.9zM11 7h6v2h-6V7zm0 4h6v2h-6v-2zm0 4h6v2h-6zM7 7h2v2H7zm0 4h2v2H7zm0 4h2v2H7z"
      ];
    return path;
};
```

When the chart is renderer on browser, the highchart return wrong icon

I've used a icon https://fontawesome.com/icons/table?style=solid

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you got that svg path, but the one you linked to is different and should be

```
  Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.download = function (x, y, w, h) {


      var path = [
          "M464 32H48C21.49 32 0 53.49 0 80v352c0 26.51 21.49 48 48 48h416c26.51 0 48-21.49 48-48V80c0-26.51-21.49-48-48-48zM224 416H64v-96h160v96zm0-160H64v-96h160v96zm224 160H288v-96h160v96zm0-160H288v-96h160v96z"
      ];
      return path;
  };
```

Comment: yeah, but using variables x,y,w,h in path? to when i can resize icons i not need pass a new path example: M x + y, wh any idea?

Comment: `x`, `y`, `w` (width) and `h` (height) allow you to create responsive shapes. Other shapes (`circle`, `square`, `triangle` etc.) in `symbols` object are good example how to do it: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/js/parts/SvgRenderer.js#L3489